# How do I get resize handles in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, resize

Is there a way to get a resize effect between two widgets? Like say I have two `QTextEdit` boxes next to eachother, I want to get a handle between them so I can move it back and forth. Sort of in the same way that the textarea I'm writing in now has a handle at the bottom for making it larger.

I'm using QT Creator and I can't seem to figure this out. I got something similar to what I want by using a QDockWidget, but that really doesn't seem like the purpose for which it was intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a [QSplitter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsplitter.html).